# Change input value in js before update panel ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

in an application developped in ASP.NET with webForms, I try to execute a javascript code before updating an update panel.

To do this, I use this code :

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_initializeRequest(myMethod);
```

The method **MyMethod** changes an input value with JavaScript :

```
$('#myinput').val('new val');
```

After that, my postback is launched. But in my CS code, the value of the input is empty. It seems that the value defined with JS is not sent width the postback.

Can you help me to solve this problem ? :)

Comment: Can you show use html?

Comment: Is your "myinput" inside that same update panel ?

Comment: @Guru Kara Yes myinput is inside the update panel

Answer (score 0):

You can check the beginrequest event of AJAX call, have a look following link
[AJAX](http://ajax.asp.net/docs/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/PageRequestManagerBeginRequestEvent.aspx)

Comment: I tried this code : Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(myMethod); but same problem : myMethod is called before the callback, the new value is ok but in my CS code, I don't have the new value ...

Comment: My CS code is simple. In Page_Load Method, the MyInput.Value is empty and not contains the new value.